# Mock Y of (from X import Y) in doctest (python)

Tags: python, testing, mocking, doctest

I'm trying to create a doctest with mock of function that resides in a separate module
and that is imported as bellow

```
from foomodule import foo

def bar():
    """
    >>> from minimock import mock
    >>> mock('foo', nsdicts=(bar.func_globals,), returns=5)
    >>> bar()
    Called foo()
    10
    """
    return foo() * 2


import doctest
doctest.testmod()
```

foomodule.py:

```
def foo():
    raise ValueError, "Don't call me during testing!"
```

This fails.

If I change import to **import foomodule**
and use **foomodule.foo** everywhere 
Then it works.

But is there any solution for mocking function imported the way above?

Comment: I'm seeing something very similar with the Mock module. Was this ever sorted out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, found out that this was rather an issue of trunk version of MiniMock.
Old stable one performs as expected.

Answer (score 5):

You've just met one of the many reasons that make it best to never import object from "within" modules -- only modules themselves (possibly from within packages).  We've made this rule part of our style guidelines at Google (published [here](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html)) and I heartily recommend it to every Python programmer.

That being said, what you need to do is to take the foomodule.foo that you've just replaced with a mock and stick it in the current module.  I don't recall enough of doctest's internal to confirm whether

```
   >>> import foomodule
   >>> foo = foomodule.foo
```

will suffice for that -- give it a try, and if it doesn't work, do instead

```
   >>> import foomodule
   >>> import sys
   >>> sys.modules[__name__].foo = foomodule.foo
```

yeah, it's a mess, but the cause of that mess is that innocent-looking `from foomodule import foo` -- eschew that, and your life will be simpler and more productive;-).

Comment: Alex, thanks for your guidelines link. I'll definitely use in addition to standard PEPs.

Comment: Published link is a 404.

Comment: It appears the current link is [Google's Python style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html) as found in their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/google/styleguide).