# Mocking ImportError in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, doctest, zope.component

I'm trying this for almost two hours now, without any luck.

I have a module that looks like this:

```
try:
    from zope.component import queryUtility  # and things like this
except ImportError:
    # do some fallback operations <-- how to test this?
```

Later in the code:

```
try:
    queryUtility(foo)
except NameError:
    # do some fallback actions <-- this one is easy with mocking 
    # zope.component.queryUtility to raise a NameError
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Alex's suggestion doesn't seem to work:

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> realimport = __builtin__.__import__
>>> def fakeimport(name, *args, **kw):
...     if name == 'zope.component':
...         raise ImportError
...     realimport(name, *args, **kw)
...
>>> __builtin__.__import__ = fakeimport
```

When running the tests:

```
aatiis@aiur ~/work/ao.shorturl $ ./bin/test --coverage .
Running zope.testing.testrunner.layer.UnitTests tests:
  Set up zope.testing.testrunner.layer.UnitTests in 0.000 seconds.


Error in test /home/aatiis/work/ao.shorturl/src/ao/shorturl/shorturl.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/unittest.py", line 260, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/doctest.py", line 2123, in runTest
    test, out=new.write, clear_globs=False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/doctest.py", line 1361, in run
    return self.__run(test, compileflags, out)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/doctest.py", line 1282, in __run
    exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/doctest.py", line 1148, in report_unexpected_exception
    'Exception raised:\n' + _indent(_exception_traceback(exc_info)))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/doctest.py", line 1163, in _failure_header
    out.append(_indent(source))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/doctest.py", line 224, in _indent
    return re.sub('(?m)^(?!$)', indent*' ', s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/re.py", line 150, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, 0).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/re.py", line 239, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/sre_compile.py", line 507, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parse'



Error in test BaseShortUrlHandler (ao.shorturl)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/unittest.py", line 260, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/doctest.py", line 2123, in runTest
    test, out=new.write, clear_globs=False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/doctest.py", line 1351, in run
    self.debugger = _OutputRedirectingPdb(save_stdout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/doctest.py", line 324, in __init__
    pdb.Pdb.__init__(self, stdout=out)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/pdb.py", line 57, in __init__
    cmd.Cmd.__init__(self, completekey, stdin, stdout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/cmd.py", line 90, in __init__
    import sys
  File "<doctest shorturl.txt[10]>", line 4, in fakeimport
NameError: global name 'realimport' is not defined
```

However, it **does** work when I run the same code from the python interactive console.

**MORE EDIT:**

I'm using `zope.testing` and a test file, `shorturl.txt` that has all the tests specific to this part of my module. First I'm importing the module with `zope.component` available, to demonstrate & test the usual usage. The absence of `zope.*` packages is considered an edge-case, so I'm testing it later. Thus, I have to `reload()` my module, after making `zope.*` unavailable, somehow.

So far I've even tried using `tempfile.mktempdir()` and empty `zope/__init__.py` and `zope/component/__init__.py` files in the tempdir, then inserting tempdir to `sys.path[0]`, and removing the old `zope.*` packages from `sys.modules`.

Didn't work either.

**EVEN MORE EDIT:**

In the meantime, I've tried this:

```
>>> class NoZope(object):
...     def find_module(self, fullname, path):
...         if fullname.startswith('zope'):
...             raise ImportError
... 

>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, NoZope())
```

And it works well for the namespace of the test suite (= for all imports in `shorturl.txt`), but it is not executed in my main module, `ao.shorturl`. Not even when I `reload()` it. Any idea why?

```
>>> import zope  # ok, this raises an ImportError
>>> reload(ao.shorturl)    <module ...>
```

Importing `zope.interfaces` raises an `ImportError`, so it doesn't get to the part where I import `zope.component`, and **it remains in the ao.shorturl namespace**. Why?!

```
>>> ao.shorturl.zope.component  # why?! 
<module ...>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just monkeypatch into the `builtins` your own version of `__import__` -- it can raise whatever you wish when it recognizes it's being called on the specific modules for which you want to mock up errors.  See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=__import__#__import__) for copious detail.  Roughly:

```
try:
    import builtins
except ImportError:
    import __builtin__ as builtins
realimport = builtins.__import__

def myimport(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level):
    if ...:
        raise ImportError
    return realimport(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)

builtins.__import__ = myimport
```

In lieu of the `...`, you can hardcode `name == 'zope.component'`, or arrange things more flexibly with a callback of your own that can make imports raise on demand in different cases, depending on your specific testing needs, without requiring you to code multiple `__import__`-alike functions;-).

Note also that if what you use, instead of `import zope.component` or `from zope.component import something`, is `from zope import component`, the `name` will then be `'zope'`, and `'component'` will then be the only item in the `fromlist`.

**Edit**: the docs for the `__import__` function say that the name to import is `builtin` (like in Python 3), but in fact you need `__builtins__` -- I've edited the code above so that it works either way.

Comment: Ah, thanks! For some reason, I tried to do `def __import__()`, but didn't assign it to `builtin.__import__`; silly me. Interesting, I was just reading your answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216828/mock-y-of-from-x-import-y-in-doctest-python/2217512#2217512 - do you think it would make this situation easier if I wouldn't import queryUtility to my module's scope?

Comment: @Attila, if you did `from zope import component` and then used `component.queryUtility`, it would make it easier, for example, to use the real thing some of the time, and a mocked-out/fake version at other times. As I wrote in that answer, I do recommend it as a general thing, and it's part of the way we code Python at Google (sometimes an `as` clause to shorten the name one imports is warranted, of course, but that doesn't change the semantics).

Comment: If you do `from zope import component`, BTW, your `__import__`-alike function will see `'zope'` as the `name` argument, and `'component'` as an item in the `fromlist` argument (the only one, unless you do `from zope import this, that, component` or the like;-); so be sure to trigger accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I'll adopt that coding style, as it seems to be helpful in cases like this. However, I've just realized that you'r answer didn't work for me (it does work on the interactive console, if I substitute `builtin` with `__builtin__`.)

Comment: It's `builtins` -- I spelled it right in the text but wrong in the code.  Editing to fix.

Comment: Ok, this is weird. Importing `builtins` raises an `ImportError` on `python2.{5.4,6.4,7a4+}`, but it works fine in `python3.{1.1,2a0}`. 2.5, 2.6, and 3.1 are provided by gentoo ebuilds, but 2.7 and 3.2 are my own builds from trunk. How come I miss the `builtins` module?

Comment: However, according to [this](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__), you're right, it should be `builtins`.

Comment: `import __builtin__` works in 2.5 -- no `s`, "magic name" (contradiciting the docs).  Editing again to fix.

Comment: Great, now it works great in the console; but still not working when used as a doctest in a text file. Anyway, this might be a `zope.testing` issue (although not sure).

In the meantime, I've tried this:

    class NoZope(object):
        def find_module(self, fullname, path):
            if fullname.startswith('zope'):
                raise ImportError
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, NoZope())


And it works well for the namespace of the test suite (= for all imports in `shorturl.txt`), but it is not executed in my main module, `ao.shorturl`. Not even when I `reload()` it. Any idea why?

Comment: Alas, Zope is deep, dark and mysterious (I do think it plays tricks with import hooks and the like, for your "convenience") so I don't really know (but I do know you should edit your Q to include this code so you can make it readable - in the comment it's basically unreadable due to lack of formatting, and there's no fix except moving it to the Q!-).

Comment: Don't be so evil. Zope is not dark, it's beautiful. But it's still deep, and mysterious indeed :) So then, one last question. Do you know any other buildout recipe for running tests, other than zope.testing? Something with good coverage support.

Comment: Dark and beautiful aren't antonyms, cfr http://www.darkisbeautiful.in/ !  I have no hands-on experience with buildout, don't the recipes at http://www.buildout.org/docs/recipelist.html help?

Comment: Not really, since most (if not all) of the testing in the zope world relies on `zope.testing`. However, it might be easy to write a recipe for another test runner, if there exists one. Will try it maybe. Anyway, thanks for all your help Alex, and for keeping this thread alive!

Answer (score 3):

This is what I justed in my unittests.

It uses [PEP-302 "New Import Hooks"](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-pep302.html). (Warning: the PEP-302 document and the more concise release notes I linked aren't exactly *accurate*.)

I use `meta_path` because it's as early as possible in the import sequence.

If the module has already been imported (as in my case, because earlier unittests mock against it), then it's necessary to remove it from sys.modules before doing the `reload` on the dependent module.

```
 # Ensure we fallback to using ~/.pif if XDG doesn't exist.

 >>> import sys

 >>> class _():
 ... def __init__(self, modules):
 ...  self.modules = modules
 ...
 ...  def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
 ...  if fullname in self.modules:
 ...   raise ImportError('Debug import failure for %s' % fullname)

 >>> fail_loader = _(['xdg.BaseDirectory'])
 >>> sys.meta_path.append(fail_loader)

 >>> del sys.modules['xdg.BaseDirectory']

 >>> reload(pif.index) #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
 <module 'pif.index' from '...'>

 >>> pif.index.CONFIG_DIR == os.path.expanduser('~/.pif')
 True

 >>> sys.meta_path.remove(fail_loader)
```

Where the code inside pif.index looks like:

```
try:
    import xdg.BaseDirectory

    CONFIG_DIR = os.path.join(xdg.BaseDirectory.xdg_data_home, 'pif')
except ImportError:
    CONFIG_DIR = os.path.expanduser('~/.pif')
```

---

To answer the question about why the newly reloaded module has properties of the old and new loads, here are two example files.

The first is a module `y` with an import failure case.

```
# y.py

try:
    import sys

    _loaded_with = 'sys'
except ImportError:
    import os

    _loaded_with = 'os'
```

The second is `x` which demonstrates how leaving handles about for a module can affect its properties when being reloaded.

```
# x.py

import sys

import y

assert y._loaded_with == 'sys'
assert y.sys

class _():
    def __init__(self, modules):
        self.modules = modules
        
    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        if fullname in self.modules:
            raise ImportError('Debug import failure for %s' % fullname)

# Importing sys will not raise an ImportError.
fail_loader = _(['sys'])
sys.meta_path.append(fail_loader)

# Demonstrate that reloading doesn't work if the module is already in the
# cache.

reload(y)

assert y._loaded_with == 'sys'
assert y.sys

# Now we remove sys from the modules cache, and try again.
del sys.modules['sys']

reload(y)

assert y._loaded_with == 'os'
assert y.sys
assert y.os

# Now we remove the handles to the old y so it can get garbage-collected.
del sys.modules['y']
del y

import y

assert y._loaded_with == 'os'
try:
    assert y.sys
except AttributeError:
    pass
assert y.os
```

Comment: Great, now I managed to raise an `ImportError`, which is all what I need. The interesting thing is this: if I reload `ao.shorturl`, and in it I have `try: import zope.component, zope.interface; except ImportError: fallback()`, and I get the first `ImportError` for `zope.component`, **zope.interface will still be available in ao.shorturl (ao.shorturl.zope.interface)**. Why is that?

Comment: I just added a further section describing why that happens. tl;dr, you need to `del ao.shorturl` before your `reload`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind changing your program itself, you could also put the import call in a function and patch that in your tests.