# Trigger ImportError to test Coverage of Fallback Code

Tags: python, testing, code-coverage, importerror

Given code like this in `somemod.py`:

```
try:
    Import cStringIO as StringIO
except ImportError:
    import StringIO
```

How can one test the 'fallback' branch?

(Use case:  trying to achieve 100% coverage.  Agreed that this is a bit of a silly goal :) )

**Complications**:

1. code runs from `test_somemod.py` which has `import somemod`
2. [Mocking ImportError in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481511/mocking-importerror-in-python) covers some of this, but is complicated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a function to use for testing:

```
>>> def somecode():
...    try:
...       import cStringIO as StringIO
...       print 'got cStringIO'
...    except ImportError:
...       import StringIO
...       print 'got StringIO'
>>> somecode()
got cStringIO
```

Now, as explained [here](http://docs.python.org/library/imputil.html), you can hook in to the import function:

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> original_import = __builtin__.__import__
>>> def import_hook(name, *args, **kwargs):
...    if name == 'cStringIO': raise ImportError('test case module import failure')
...    else: return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> 
>>> __builtin__.__import__ = import_hook
>>> somecode()
got StringIO
```

After the test case, you should set it back:

```
>>> __builtin__.__import__ = original_import
```

Comment: For extra credit, any way to get mock.patch involved to do this only for particular test cases?

Comment: Hmm, never used mock.patch, but it should be easy to make this into a decorator where you can give it a list of modules to 'hide' on enter and set back on exit.

Comment: So far, it seems like messing around with import gives some ugliness.  My real solution is to use "# pragma: no cover" to make coverage.py ignore it!  I will have to dig out my experiements.