# I want to cause an ImportError

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to reach 100% testing coverage in a bit of code that I'm writing. The following block of code, however, is giving me trouble.

```
try:
    from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
    add_introspection_rules([], ["^localized_recurrence\.duration_field\.DurationField"])
except ImportError:
    pass
```

The code above is part of my module under test. I need to create a test (without modifying the code above) which follows the `ImportError` branch.

How can I programmatically cause the `ImportError` to occur, while only writing code in my tests?

Comment: What about `raise ImportError`?

Comment: I should be clear, The code above is the code under test, I want to cause the error without modifying that code, but rather from a test. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: I understand, you want to force that code to fail with `ImportError`.

Comment: I've used this in my unit tests, http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises

Comment: Edgar: that tests that the code raises an exception, I want the opposite, I want to force it to be raised in the block above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mocking ImportError in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481511/mocking-importerror-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd try patching `sys.modules` and replacing `south.modelsinspector` with a mock module.

See [the docs on Import statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-import_stmt) for inspiration.

```
In [1]: from re import sub

In [2]: import sys

In [3]: sys.modules['re'] = {}

In [4]: from re import sub
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/kos/codility/frontend_v2/<ipython-input-4-6d4794835d43> in <module>()
----> 1 from re import sub

ImportError: cannot import name sub
```

You can do it in a narrow context by using `mock.patch.dict` (as a test decorator or context manager):

```
In [6]: with mock.patch.dict('sys.modules', {'re': {}}):
            from re import sub
   ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-7479025ab931> in <module>()
      1 with mock.patch.dict('sys.modules', {'re': {}}):
----> 2     from re import sub
      3 

ImportError: cannot import name sub

In [8]: from re import sub

In [9]:
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm going to give this a shot.

Comment: I spent a significant amount of time trying to get this to work. It eventually did, but I needed to use `reload(my_module_under_test)` from within the patch context manager for the patch to be applied on import of that file. With that additional detail (feel free to edit it into this answer), I'm accepting this as the correct answer for my problem. Thanks so much Kos!

Answer (score 3):

You can change [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.path#sys.path) for the test. For example:

```
>>>import bs4
>>>

>>>import sys
>>>p=sys.path
>>>sys.path=['']
>>>import bs4

ImportError: No module named bs4

>>>sys.path=p
>>>import bs4
>>>
```

Just modify `sys.path` for that specific test on `setUp()` and later on `tearDown()` restore it.

Hope this helps!